# hold data on tableview cell ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, missing-data

I'm newbie in IOS and again i face another issue. How can i prevent data vanish from a table cell when i scroll a tableview.

[image]

I'm using the code below to load data on the table...Works fine but the data disappear when table cell go in not visible to the screen.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    list = [self.listas objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"drop";
    item_drop *cell = (item_drop*) [tabela_listas dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"item_drop" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.texto_drop.text = list.nome_lista;
    return cell;
}
```

In android i used a holder to do it. There is anything similiar on IOS?

Comment: Is "item_drop" a UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: "item_drop" is a custom UITableViewCell

Comment: What happens when you scroll back up, in terms of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method? Is the cell dequeued from the tableView, and then you set the text on it properly? I know that's what the code should do, but I'm asking as to whether or not the loadNib call is being called when scrolling back up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using reusable cells of a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, make sure you register the cell identifier in the UITableView, associating it to your custom cell type. i.e:

```
[yourTableView registerClass:[item_drop class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"drop"];
```

You typically do this when you configure subviews in the UIViewController that controls the view your UITableView is a part of, in `viewDidLoad`.

With that in place, you should never hit the code inside `if (cell == nil)`.